# HealthKit and accessories with no companion iOS apps

Tags: ios, healthkit

If I understand it correctly, HealthKit can automatically connect with bluetooth accessories of the following types - heart rate monitor, glucose sensor, blood pressure monitor, health thermometer.

There is no need to have companion apps for them as they can write the data directly (and of course wirelessly) to HealthKit.

I am just curious if it is true and if so do all these accessories work seamlessly with HealthKit. Is no configuration needed. Has anyone tried it.

Further there are some accessories (such as the iHealth blood pressure monitor) which do the measurement only once the measurement is initiated from the companion app. So how do those tie-in.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 8, the system can import data from a BTLE heart rate monitor directly into HealthKit with no companion app.  This can be configured in the Bluetooth settings pane of iOS.

There is a WWDC video that goes into more detail about this available [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=701).  Also, if you have an idea for a HealthKit accessory that is not supported currently, you should contact Apple with this [form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/healthkit/).

Comment: Have you been able to do it yourself. Is it that any bluetooth heart rate monitor will seamlessly connect to HealthKit.

Comment: Wow - very cool.  I did not know this, but can confirm that it it is working with Wahoo's Blue Heart Rate Monitor v1.7.  BPM data is flowing into HealthKit about 1 datapoint every second.

Comment: It works with a Polar H7 heart rate monitor. But so far as I can see it's pretty useless. It records the heart rate and time-of-day every second whenever the monitor is connected, with no link to any other information such as what you are doing (running, climbing, reading, sleeping) and no concept of the start or end of an activity. And it doesn't record any other information that the monitor transmits. It's also pretty unreliable about connecting/disconnecting. I'm probably missing the point of HK. I would be grateful if someone who knows would say how this could be used in a useful app.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what was said during WWDC 2014, it appears only Heart Rate is available.

From [HKSource Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSource_Class/index.html):

> Source objects represents the different data sources in HealthKit. These sources may include apps and devices whose data can be directly imported into the HealthKit store. **Currently, HealthKit supports only the direct import of heart rate data from Bluetooth LE devices**. All other devices need a companion app to collect and save the data to HealthKit.